# How to programmatically uninstall unsused packages in ProTeXt?

Tags: packages, installing, protext

The TeX distribution for Windows [ProTeXt](https://www.tug.org/protext/) comes with a full installation similar to TeXlive.  In a regular document one never uses *all* packages from the repositories.  Therefore my question is, how can one uninstall unneeded packages from ProTeXt, either manually, or even better programmatically, based on the preamble of an existing document.

Comment: Disk space is cheap, better have all the packages and don't care about it too much. Almost all packages have dependencies on other packages. Which package is really needed is often hard to find out.

Comment: MikTeX (which proTeXt is based on) has a package manager that will probably let you do that. You can find it in the start menu.

Comment: By the way, your questioin ttle and question body seem to be asking two completely different topics.

Comment: On some systems it's possible to install a base TeX installation and add packages later. That works well if you don't want to install everything. Your question title doesn't match the question body - the former is about each document, the latter about the installation.

Comment: @Johannes_B disk space is cheap on a conventional PC or laptop, but TeX runs very well on low spec systems, and the 4GB of texlive-full on Ubuntu is a large fraction of the flash on something like a chromebook.

Comment: Well, thanks. Since the packages have dependencies on other i think is a better idea not to erase them. 
About the question/topic: im new around here, im learning how it works. Thanks for the coments :)

Comment: Please stop voting to close this question.  I think it is a valid question which just needs some polishing.  I will edit it.